# OS swap alway increase until max

Tags: java, ubuntu, apache-nifi

I run Nifi on Ubuntu 16 with 8Go Ram / 1Go OS swap and configure Nifi to use :
java.arg.2=-Xms4g,
java.arg.3=-Xmx6g

My problem is that the OS swap always full after certain time, even, if my Nifi app don't consume all heap memory.

jvmtop show me that only 2Go / 6Go is use in general

and my server :
980M / 980M swap use
and its the Nifi java process take all.

I play with swappiness and put it at 1, but its always the same result.

Have you some idea ?

Answer (score 0):

-Xmx6g on your setup is dangerously close to the total amount of memory available to the OS to use for itself and the apps you run. I'd try increasing the amount of system memory if it's a VM or Docker instance.